# Julia syntax highlighting in julia-vim

Tags: vim, julia

I use gvim with julia-vim for editing julia code. I am using julia 0.5 on a mac and installed julia-vim with vundle.

My problem is that files with the `.jl` extension do not have appropriate highlighting. For example, `if` is highlighted but `for` is not. Any solution for this?

Comment: `ji` extension, or `jl` extension?
You shouldn't be editting `.ji` files.

Comment: `jl` extension. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.jl` files are sometimes recognized as `lisp` files by default, (blame [Sawfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawfish_(window_manager))) so that's probably the syntax highlighting you're getting. (type `defun` and `progn` and etc and see if the pretty colors pop up)

You were close when you said the correct solution was `:set syntax=julia`, what you need is to set `filetype` plus some `autocmd` magicks to make that happen every time you open a `.jl` file.

Put something like this in some file (e.g. `jl.vim`) in your [`ftdetect`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#ftdetect) directory:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jl :set filetype=julia
```

And that should do it.

---

**Addendum 1**: Changing `filetype` instead of `syntax` may be required to trigger additional features like the LaTeX expansions depending on the root of your problem, so that's what I am using.

---

**Addendum 2**: Note that this should've been handled by the `julia-vim` plugin, but conflicts with other scripts can mess with that. You can use `:scriptnames` to see what scripts have been loaded and in what order, and try to debug what could be causing the conflict, if you think that's worth the trouble.

---

**Addendum 3**: Also related is that `Vundle` has some specific configurations that need to be made when it comes to filetypes, so that could also be causing this. However, I've seen this and similar problems happen outside `Vundle` for any number of reasons so I still believe that the solution at the top is the best one, and will possibly prevent some future headaches.

Comment: Great. That fixed the Problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Could you check if the LaTeX expansions are working with just the `:set syntax=julia`? e.g. type `:\alpha` then `Shift-Tab` and it should become a alpha symbol. (or turn invisible but that is just my Unicode-illiterate terminal) And if changing from `:set syntax=julia` to `:set filetype=julia` still solves the problem plus enables these if they are not there?

Comment: When I use `:set syntax=julia` the `.jl` files are still interpreted as `lisp` and so LaTeX expansions do not work. They work with `:set filetype=julia`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for checking! I was pretty sure that was the right solution but for some reason here the syntax change was triggering the filetype change as well so I couldn't confirm. I won't bother you anymore, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

After testing [`julia-vim`](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim) I think the issue is likely with the color scheme you are using.

Try using a different one.

`:colorscheme desert`

I tried it with the built-in `desert` and both `if` and `for` were highlighted (see below).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. I think that the that vim does not automatically detect the `julia` filetype. When I use `:set syntax=julia` I get the correct highlighting.

Comment: @Thomas That is odd as the [`ftdetect` is setup correctly](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim/blob/master/ftdetect/julia.vim#L8).

Comment: @sbdchd Oh that's a thing too isn't it? The plugin should've just handled it. When I first installed `julia-vim` via `vim-plug` I had this issue and created a `jl.vim` file of my own in the main `ftdetect` directory. But now I just removed my `jl.vim` and am not having the issue anymore. Hmmm. Welp time to spend the rest of the day trying to figure this one out least I won't be able to sleep.

Comment: @sbdchd I said I don't have the issue anymore but then I am in a julia file and paredit is on and I just typed a `slimv` command and a swank server opened up, so um... I think I am putting that `jl.vim` file back. I will edit my answer with possible reasons for this whole mess.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the instructions [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781788998369/1/ch01lvl1sec14/julia-support-for-text-editors) worked a treat. Namely

```
git clone https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim.git
mkdir -p ~/.vim
cp -R julia-vim/* ~/.vim
```

Note: I realise that the OP claims to have already installed Julia-Vim using Vundle, but I came to this question because Vim was automatically using LISP syntax highlighting for me, and the above was enough for me. So I am sharing in case anyone comes from the same boat as me (i.e. the problem is not Vundle related) :)

Comment: Nowadays you must use `https://` instead of `git://`.