# Easy way to get syntax highlighting for Julia in Vim

Tags: vim, terminal, julia, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I am trying to get Julia to have syntax highlighting in Vim. Unfortunately, at the moment, I there is no syntax highlighting ([here is a small snippet of my code so you can see what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLViE.jpg)). I tried installing julia-vim and putting it in the .vimrc file and installing it, but it doesn't actually change the highlighting. Below is the .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
  set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
 call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
  Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
  Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own 
   plugin)
  Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
 " The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
 " Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
 Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
 " Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
  " different version somewhere else.
 " Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
   call vundle#end()            " required
   filetype plugin indent on    " required
  " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
  "filetype plugin on
  "
  " Brief help
  " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
   " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or 
    just :PluginUpdate
   " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
   " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append 
   `!` to auto-approve removal
   "

   Plugin 'JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim'


  "
  "
  "
  " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
  " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

I'm also note sure how to fix it after [reading the julia-vim documentation](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim). Am I doing anything incorrectly, or is there another way to add some syntax highlighting to Julia?

I have seen from one of the answers to [this question asked by @Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698782/julia-syntax-highlighting-in-julia-vim) that it might be how I have set up my terminal, but I'd prefer to keep the terminal with the present color scheme if possible. [See here for my current settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99sAU.png)

EDIT: Thanks to @axwr, I was able to get some syntax highlighting by putting

```
  syntax on
```

at the end of the .vimrc file and then running

```
   :so %
```

while editing the .vimrc file. However, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ny4p.jpg), the color coding seems to be less than ideal. Only certain packages come up as yellow, the majority is still green, and random things (usually numbers) come up as purple. Is this how julia-vim colors things, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you run PluginInstall after putting that line in your vimrc file?

Comment: @axwr Yes I did; in the .vimrc file, I ran :PluginInstall after editing the .vimrc file itself

Comment: Also, could you just paste in your entire vimrc in a codeblock? It will make it much easier to diagnose the issue

Comment: After editing *and* sourcing the vimrc file?

Comment: I'll upload the whole vimrc in a moment. Also, sorry, I'm a little new to vim: to source, do I just write "so ~/.vimrc" in the command line?

Comment: Yes, in the vim command line its `:source ~/.vimrc`, or just reopening vim does it as well. No worries, we were all new to it once.

Comment: Ok, I just uploaded the whole .vimrc file. I also tried running  :source ~/.vimrc in vi, but it didn't do anything. I also tried running :so % while editing the .vimrc, and still no syntax highlighting when I bring up the Julia code in vi

Comment: No, sorry not a picture of the code, the actual code, copy and paste it into a code block in the text. It's generally bad practice to screenshot code on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry; I just uploaded the code for the .vimrc file in a codeblock.

Comment: can you put the line `syntax on` at the bottom of your rc file, close vim, then open a .jl file?

Comment: This gives me some colors, but it seems to not be very consistent...I just edited my question with a picture.

Comment: Can you try to use just the settings i described in my answer, with the sample Julia code. Also, the file extension needs to be correct for vim to know its a julia file.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it works now. Thank you. I actually think the problem might have been that I didn't include the Julia-vim plugin before the last call vundle, but whatever it was it definitely works now.

Comment: Awesome, great to hear. Happy Hacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so.

There are two steps to syntax highlighting in Vim; actually turning it on, and, having the ability to highlight the specific language you want to work in. For most languages vim can do this by default, however some languages, like Julia, require a little help. In this case you have done step two by using vundle to install a Julia plugin.

To acheive step one, you just need the line: `syntax on` in your vimrc file.
A minimal example vimrc for you, might look like:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim'
call vundle#end()

set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set number
set hidden

syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Given the above settings, and a terminal that has the "solarised" colorscheme, a julia file looks like:

[image]

Here is the little fizzbuzz julia snippet so you can compare against your highlighting:

```
for i in 1:100
    if i % 15 == 0
        println("FizzBuzz")
    elseif i % 3 == 0
        println("Fizz")
    elseif i % 5 == 0
        println("Buzz")
    else
        println(i)
    end
end
```

So, Step by step:

- Add `syntax on` to your `.vimrc`
- Add `filetype plugin indent on` to your `.vimrc`
- Install the relevant plugin
- Source your `.vimrc` or close vim.
- open a file with the correct extension, i.e: `test.jl`